# how to find which linux kernel commit made its way to exactly which kernel version

Tags: linux-kernel

We have a problem that started appearing in kernel-uek-3.8.13-68.1.2.el6uek.x86_64.

Symptoms and description matches exactly this linux kernel developers description
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/ChangeLog-3.18.1

```
xen-netfront: use correct linear area after linearizing an skb

[ Upstream commit 11d3d2a16cc1f05c6ece69a4392e99efb85666a6 ]

Commit 97a6d1bb2b658ac85ed88205ccd1ab809899884d (xen-netfront: Fix
handling packets on compound pages with skb_linearize) attempted to
fix a problem where an skb that would have required too many slots
would be dropped causing TCP connections to stall.

However, it filled in the first slot using the original buffer and not
the new one and would use the wrong offset and grant access to the
wrong page.

Netback would notice the malformed request and stop all traffic on the
VIF, reporting:

    vif vif-3-0 vif3.0: txreq.offset: 85e, size: 4002, end: 6144
    vif vif-3-0 vif3.0: fatal error; disabling device

Reported-by: Anthony Wright <anthony@overnetdata.com>
Tested-by: Anthony Wright <anthony@overnetdata.com>
Signed-off-by: David Vrabel <david.vrabel@citrix.com>
Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
Signed-off-by: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
```

We had no this issue on kernel-uek-3.8.13-55.1.2.el6uek.x86_64.
Tried to upgrade further to kernel-uek-3.8.13-68.2.2.el6uek.x86_64 - problem is still there.

OVM guests lose network interface connectivity after guest (not hypervisor) was upgraded to this kernel.

Wanted to track if that commit number matches any of these kernels?
How do I see which linux kernel commit is in which kernel?